# Hibernate lazy loading isn't working in @OneToOne Mapping

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Although Lazy loading is applied, still it is running all 4 queries,
but I'm fetching only:

```
   System.out.println("Author's Name: " + b.getEmail());


    public class Author  {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private String email;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Book book;
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Address address;
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Location location;
    }
public class BooksManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Author b = (Author) session.get(Author.class, 6L);
        System.out.println("Author's Name: " + b.getEmail());
    }
}
```

It's running all 4 queries for the above code:

```
Hibernate: select author0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I1_1_0_, author0_.email as email2_1_0_, author0_.name as name3_1_0_ from AUTHOR author0_ where author0_.AUTHOR_ID=?

Hibernate: select address0_.address_id as address_1_0_0_, address0_.description as descript2_0_0_, address0_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE3_0_0_, address0_.title as title4_0_0_ from ADDRESS address0_ where address0_.address_id=?

Hibernate: select book0_.book_id as book_id1_2_0_, book0_.description as descript2_2_0_, book0_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE3_2_0_, book0_.title as title4_2_0_ from BOOK book0_ where book0_.book_id=?

Hibernate: select location0_.location_id as location1_3_0_, location0_.description as descript2_3_0_, location0_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE3_3_0_, location0_.title as title4_3_0_ from LOCATION location0_ where location0_.location_id=?
```

Comment: What's `session`? This example is not even complete.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition it, all 3 OneToOne relationships are optional (nullable).
when hibernate loads the entity Author, it has to create 3 proxies for relationships. but if a property is null , hibernate should not create proxy for that property.
Now hibernate somehow has to know whether the property is null or not.
so it has to lookup all other 3 tables to detect that. 
finally hibernate is intelligent enough to ignore the hint made for LAZY loading and load them eagerly.

Comment: then for this what is the solution

Comment: change your design, it is not natural, one author can write one book? if author has an address why address keeps the author id, instead of it should be other way around.

Comment: it's an sample code , in project this is requirement , I can change the relationship @OneToMany  It'll resolve my problem also but I want in @ OneToOne mapping is  there any other solution